# Displaying three cells in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have made a collection view which shows image in a grid format. The code is given as follows...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    let array:[String] = ["1", "2", "3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3 - 3

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize + 100)

        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 3

        myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout


    }

    //Number of views
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    //Populate view
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
        cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")
        return cell

    }
```

Now this displays the cells like so...

[image]

But I want the images to be seen like so..
[image]

For that I added this block of code towards the end of the above given lines of code...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if array.count == 3 {
        if array[indexPath.row] == "1" {
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 200)
        }
        if array[indexPath.row] == "2" {
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
        if array[indexPath.row] == "3" {
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

But this displays the images like so...

[image]

What am I doing wrong here..? Also is there a better approach..?

EDIT 1: If there are 5 images it is show like so...

[image]

Comment: In sizeForItemAt, when return height and width, also count inset of cell

Comment: Ok @Amita...but could u mind suggesting as to how I can do that..?

Comment: Ok, For example return height of cell 2 and 3 as 90. When height of cell is 100 its add cell inset to that and hight of cell compare to first cell increased

Comment: It isn't working @Amita. Even if I give the height and width as 90 for cells 2 & 3, it is still shown as in the last screenshot given in the question above..

Comment: What is width of collection view?

Comment: collection View width >= 300 ?

Comment: yes..the width of the collectionview is the entire width of the screen in storyboard i.e. 375 and its height is 647

Comment: then you have to increase cell width

Comment: is it fixed that you want show the 3 images in that format??

Comment: Actually @Manish_Nainwal I wanted to show 3 and 5 images. The images wont be more than 5 on the collectionview..I have edited the question and added a pic for the layout of 5 images..

Comment: @asd2 for this need to update layout of `UICollectionView`, [SquareFlowLayout](https://github.com/ChernyshenkoTaras/SquareFlowLayout) is similar to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom layout as described in the below link.

[Raywenderlich - Collection View Custom Layout Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)